# Responsive TailwindCSS grid-col

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I want the grid-col model to change to three columns in a row for smaller devices.
This would be the desired grid for smaller devices:

```html
<div class="bg-green-100 sm:bg-yellow-500">          
  <div class="grid grid-cols-3 sm:grid-cols-8 gap-2 text-left pb-6">

    <div class="col-span-1 bg-gray-400">left</div>
    <div class="col-span-1 sm:col-span-2 bg-green-400">
        <span class="font-bold">col 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-span-1 sm:col-span-2 bg-green-400">
      <span class="font-bold">col 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-span-1 sm:col-span-2 bg-green-400">
       <span class="font-bold">col 3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-span-1 bg-gray-400">right</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/N1WRbkB84I

**This would be the desired grid for smaller devices:**

```
[left] [col 1] [right]
[left] [col 2] [right]
[left] [col 3] [right]
```

To be honest I am just starting to understand the grid model. And I can't find the right way myself. Therefore my question to the experts here.

Comment: Is this a [layout](https://play.tailwindcss.com/RbbPDcVS0K) you want to achieve? Left and right should be one column?

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka Yes! great :-) It is possible that left and right are smaller?

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka If you can make an answer then I could accepted the answer

Comment: Like [this](https://play.tailwindcss.com/JaY552drRT?size=540x720)?

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka no. i meaned less width for the first and last gray colored column. width in one row: 20% 60% 20% but i think that i can do.

Comment: Or you mean smaller in width? Basically what am I doing - just telling the element which column or row it should start (with `col-start-n`) and after that back it on original position with `col-start-auto` or `row-start-auto`. This [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-column) may help to understand Tailwind grid more

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242275/discussion-between-krassverpeilt-and-ihar-aliakseyenka).

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, you wish to turn your 5 column row into a 3 column row when the viewport is resized from tablet/pc (xl, lg, md) to mobile (sm, xs)?

If that is the case, let's think of the problem like this; The best way to utilise tailwind is **Mobile-First**. This means that all sizes, unless specified, will be the default size for mobile devices. It's better to design for a mobile site first rather than a desktop site because the majority of sites are viewed on mobile nowadays. So if we think of our grid as being split into 5 columns, it is better to do less typing and specify our grid definition at each breakpoint rather than defining spans at different breakpoints.

We will set the grid definition to default to 3 columns per row. Then we will add a breakpoint for another grid definition, `sm:grid-cols-5`. What this means is by default, all viewports smaller than md (tablet) will show 3 columns per row by default.

```
<div class='grid grid-cols-3 md:grid-cols-5'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/PzK2CVFRuH

Answer (score 0):

to make it more scalable, you could write a css class and apply tailwind classes for granular adjusmtments

```
.root {
  @apply grid gap-0 grid-cols-1;

  @screen lg {
   @apply grid-cols-3 grid-rows-2;
   // you can customize height or other properties for large screens      
  }

  @screen sm {
   @apply grid-cols-5 grid-rows-2;
   // you can customize height or other properties for small screens
  }
}
```

Comment: apply is not supported within nested at-rules like @screen.

Comment: it used to. maybe new version does not. I have to confirm

Comment: I tired it but the approach is different now, at today is @media(sm){ your content } I was curious cause is a funny feature that I didn't had :D